# Add a custom object to the Account layout in a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, page-layout

I am developing a Salesforce app for my company. The plan is that this will eventually be a managed package that will be released on the Salesforce App Exchange.

One of my first tasks was to create our own custom version of Notes, where we could keep investor data. So I have InvestorNote, and these belong to Accounts. So I wanted to see how to make sure that the InvestorNotes are listed on whatever Account page they belong to. This turned out to be easy. I found a good article here:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h3AeAAI

But how do I recreate this as part of the Managed Package? When our customers install our app, how can I be sure that this custom object will be listed on the Account pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straight answer is as an ISV you cannot control the page layout of subscriber org.

The options are below

1.Document a post install step for customer to drag the related list from the Related list page

2.You can create a custom account page layout which has related list already and your customers will assign that layout to the user

3.Of you want to further automate this then you will need to use metadata API in apex to do the assignment via admin page or set up page .This will be lot of code .

Comment: Of point #3, can you point me to any examples?

Comment: You have to put that as another question :)

Comment: But that was the question, I'm looking for how to do this.

Comment: For any questions like that the community will look for what exactly have you tried ?If you can throw some code and make a question will be happy to help through .

Comment: Here is a metadata API guide and you can use Javascript to invoke the API https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm